# UsbDevice.SendControlOutTransferAsync results in "A device attached to the system is not functioning. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007001F)"

Tags: uwp, usb

I am working on a UWP sample app that connects a windows desktop to an android device via USB. I am using UsbDevice class. I can successfully discover the devices and get the device object too(i.e. establish a connection with the device). But when I try to send a control transfer packet i.e. at this line, "device.SendOutControlTransferAsync(initSetupPacket);"
I get this:
Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll
An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
A device attached to the system is not functioning. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007001F)

What can be the reason for this error? I tried updating the USB drivers, rebooting the system, trying other android devices. Still no luck.

```
string aqs = UsbDevice.GetDeviceSelector(vid, pid);

var myDevices = await 
Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqs, null);

if (myDevices.Count == 0)
{
    ShowError("Device not found!");
    return;
}

//get the device object 
UsbDevice device = await UsbDevice.FromIdAsync(myDevices[0].Id);

// Send a control transfer. 

UsbSetupPacket initSetupPacket = new UsbSetupPacket() 
{ 
   Request = initRequest,
   RequestType = new UsbControlRequestType() { 

       Recipient = UsbControlRecipient.DefaultInterface,

       ControlTransferType = UsbControlTransferType.Vendor 
   } 
 };
await device.SendOutControlTransferAsync(initSetupPacket);
```

Comment: Have you added the [Usb device capability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/updating-the-app-manifest-with-usb-device-capabilities) declaration in "Package.appxmanifest" file?

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT I've added that. And I am able to connect the 2 devices, it's just that during control transfer it shows this error.

Comment: I made a project(target version 17134) and used your code to test on OS build 17134. It did work. I have not got the exception. What's your project's target version and OS build version?

Comment: target version 16299 and OS Build 16299.547

Comment: Could you please try it on target 17134 and OS build 17134?

Comment: I'm getting this exact same problem

Comment: You could try accessing the device by Hid instead of Usb. I've gotten this working here https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Hid.Net/blob/master/Hid.Net.UWP/UWPHidDevice.cs